# SCRAPY - how to set a default path for project creation

Tags: scrapy

when creating a Scarpy project with:

scrapy startproject xxx

The project xxx will be placed under the current folder. Is there any way I can set a default path, say C:/Projects/Scrapy/ such that whenever the command above is used, the project will be put under this path.

Thanks

SK

Answer (score 2):

You can't set a default one. But you can specify where you create it

```
scrapy startproject xxx C:/Projects/Scrapy/
```

If you still want to override it then you will need to create windows batch file and use that batch file to create project